# Weird internet connection errors

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

**Problem:**

I have a weird internet connection problem where certain sites I am unable to view specific content for some indeterminate period of time, and I'm not sure where to start solving it.

**Specifics:**

Often, when I am pretty sure I have internet connection with 300+ Kb/s, there are some strange connection errors I have trouble accessing.

For instance, when I view my stack-exchange user account, the images for some of the other linked stack-exchange websites are x'ed out. Then if I click on one of the x'ed out sites, I get "could not find server error", and I can't access that particular stack-exchange site. It's weird because I can browse through some of the other ones just fine.

When I search Google images, around half of the images seem to be x'ed out. If I click on x'ed out images, a majority of the time, the site seems to be down, although other times, I can load the image just fine.

When I watch videos on Hulu, sometimes the video fails to load and it tells me to clear the cache. I clear the cache "from beginning of time", and often it still fails to load.

On some websites, including Youtube, often the I get the page unformatted as though the css files were missing.

In fact, on websites with images in general, often a good number of the images are x'ed out.

**Background:**

This problem has been pretty prevalent for a few months now. A few weeks ago, I moved to a different house, and although it is not as severe, it still happens every now and then.

I let it go on for this long because kind of lazy and I figured I could live with it, but then it got into my head that it might be related to a security problem, then it grew really scary.

Right now I am using Chrome on Mac OS X Lion, but the same problems have come up on my iPad,  virtual machines running on the Mac (Debian, openSUSE, PinguyOS), a laptop with windows 8 developer preview, windows 7, a couple of Linux partitions (Ubuntu and PinguyOS).

It seems really weird to me because it's prevalent on all my computers and it persisted even after I moved to a new home.

Comment: Is this over a wireless our wired connection? This sounds like a packet forwarding issue.

Comment: @Sion They are all wireless connections. I don't think I've tried it wired.

Comment: At the moment of the problem, what happens if you close and re-open the browser?  Same idea, if you close the browser, clear the temp net cache out, and re-open the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried changing your Router?

If you haven't then the Router seems the most obvious suspect, and the most obvious thing to try is changing it.

If you moved house and you have the problem on many computers, as you say, that helps to rule out a lot.

Comment: I've been using AT&T U-verse, and I'm using the modem & router in one that came with the service. I think I might still have a router from when I used to use DSL. Would connecting the old router through wire make a difference?

Comment: yes try wired too. with each router. you have to change things and find what is the constant player in the problem.